# Union Template with std::variant and std::visit

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, eigen

I'm using a template library and since in my code one of the template parameters can assume a finite range of values, I decided to use, under suggestion, std::variant and declare in it all the objects I will possibly need:

```
std::variant<TemplateClass<1>, TemplateClass<2>, ..., TemplateClass<5>>
```

I never used this utility.

To access the methods of TemplateClass I have to use `std::visit`, but sometimes it works and other it doesn't, say `no member function XXX in std::variant < .... >` or "In instantiation of function template specialization ... " [I don't even understand what is the problem here]

Specifically, I'm using `Eigen::Tensor` library and when I call methods like `rank()`, `dimension(n)`, it works, while for methods like `dimensions()` and `setRandom()` it doesn't.

Below a draft of my implementation

```
std::variant<Eigen::Tensor<double, 1>, Eigen::Tensor<double, 2>, /* ... */> makeTensor(
    int i, const std::initializer_list<int> dims) {
  switch (i) {
    case 1: {
      Eigen::Tensor<double, 1> T1;
      T1.resize(dims);
      return T1;
    }

    case 2: {
      Eigen::Tensor<double, 2> T2;
      T2.resize(dims);
      return T2;
    }

      /* ... */
  }
}

int main() {
  auto myTensor{makeTensor(2, {4, 5})};  // Tensor 2D 4x5

  // Working methods
  auto rnk = std::visit([](const auto &tensor) { return tensor.rank(); }, myTensor);

  auto dim1 = std::visit([](const auto &tensor) { return tensor.dimension(0); }, myTensor);

  // Not working methods

  auto dimsTens =
      std::visit([](const auto &tensor) { return tensor.dimensions(); }, myTensor);  // 5 times same error saying
  //'In instantiation of function template specialization 'std::visit<(lambda at
  /// home/virginie/Desktop/Project/main.cpp:62:33),
  // std::variant<Eigen::Tensor<double, 1, 0, long>, Eigen::Tensor<double, 2, 0, long>, Eigen::Tensor<double, 3, 0,
  // long>, Eigen::Tensor<double, 4, 0, long>, Eigen::Tensor<double, 5, 0, long>> &>''

  std::visit([&myTensor]() { myTensor.setRandom(); });  // 'No member setRandom() in std::variant<...>'
}
```

Am I using `std::visit` in the wrong way?

---- EDIT ----

After the suggestion of @florestan, I have solved the problem related to `dimensions()`, while with `setRandom` I get the following:

In file included from /..../ main.cpp
[image]
required from here
[image]

Comment: Assuming that all variant members have `rank()` and `dimension(int)` members ***that return the same type***, this seems to be correct. If you're getting a compilation error it means that either not all of them have the class member, or they return different types.

Comment: dimensions() should return an array of length equal to the order of the tensor (1,2,3,...5). How can I solve this problem? What about setRandom(), for sure it is a class member because if I write 'Eigen::Tensor<double,2> A({4,5})' and then I call 'A.setRamdom()' it works

Comment: That's because, most likely, every `setRandom` returns a `void`. It is fundamental to C++ that all objects have ***an explicit*** type. `auto rank=` must have some specific deduced type. However if visitors `return` different types, depending on the value in the variant, the actual type of `auto rank` must vary, ***at runtime***. C++ does not work this way. Most likely because `auto rnk` itself must be a `variant` of all possible return types, and assigned directly by the visitor, instead of returning, with each visitor returning void.

Comment: Any reason why you really need the std::variant?

Comment: Because one of the template parameters (the order of the tensor) is information I can know only at run-time

Comment: For reference, [here](https://gitlab.com/libeigen/eigen/-/blob/3.3.7/unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/src/Tensor/Tensor.h#L102) is the `dimensions()` function and [`here`](https://gitlab.com/libeigen/eigen/-/blob/3.3.7/unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/src/Tensor/TensorBase.h#L849-856) is `setRandom()`. As suggested, the returned type [`DSizes`](https://gitlab.com/libeigen/eigen/-/blob/3.3.7/unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/src/Tensor/TensorDimensions.h#L259-331) has a template parameter for the rank. Maybe you could wrap it into a `Array<IndexType, Dynamic, 1>` (e.g. `ArrayXi`).

Comment: Are you sure, you're using the exactly same code as in my answer? According to the godbolt link gcc, clang and msvc do compile it without errors.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake! Thank you

Comment: For `setRandom()`, in the code you posted you are trying to call the method in the variant object, you should do it through a visitor as in the other cases, like `std::visit([](const auto &tensor) { tensor.setRandom(); }, myTensor);`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to return the same type for all possible alternatives. In case of `dimension`, you need to copy the array elements to a vector, for example.

Something like this should help:

```
 auto dimsTens=std::visit(
    [](const auto &tensor) {
       auto dims = tensor.dimensions();
       return std::vector<int>(dims.begin(), dims.end());
    }, myTensor);
```

The second error is because you don't call `std::visit` the right way. It needs two params, first the function and second the variant to visit. The following should work.

```
std::visit([](auto& t){ t.setRandom();}, myTensor);
```

Live code:
https://godbolt.org/z/vq4PYo

Comment: I am implementing a method and still have problems with std::visit. I think I have not understood something about this utility, furthermore errors are indecipherable and do not help me understand what is wrong. The method should return a copy of the object tensor, so I'm in a case where I have different return types according to the variant. How do I handle this?
Here the link of my implementation.   
https://godbolt.org/z/e37Mqd

Comment: There are several problems in your code. Please be careful when creating your examples, e.g. `MyTensor` is not the same as `myTensor`! After digging abit, it seems the problem is that `tensor.shuffle(...)` does not return a tensor but a tensor expression wich is not implicitly convertible to tensor. I'm not deep enough into Eigen to tell you how to fix that. The other thing is, that you can't return different types from std::visit, so you need to capture the result tensor variant in the lambda (by reference) and do the assignment withing the lambda.

Comment: But tbh, your whole approach seems a bit unidiomatic, perhaps you should think a bit if you really need that whole variant stuff. Perhaps you could also go with rank-5 tensors and just make the unnecessary dimensions singular? Or maybe you can factor out the run-time dependency somehow?

Comment: I will consider it, Thank you. Again